# Proper syntax for gnu make for handling different pre-requisites differently

Tags: c++, makefile

I've just recently make a switch in my program from static libraries to shared objects and am trying to figure out how to **properly** update my Makefile accordingly.  I have found a solution that appears to work correctly, using double-colon rules.  However, I am really unsure of the implications of what I have done, and whether this is, in fact, the correct way to address this problem.

I'm not sure if it makes any difference here, but as a background, my Makefile follows the approach suggested by Emile van Bergen here: http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html

The shared objects are all collected in a variable called TGT_SO.  I also have a bunch of object files which need to be included in the executable file -- the particular rule I am working on is for my unit tests, and these object files are all collected in a variable called TGT_TESTS.

Previously, the rule/recipe was straightforward:

```
tests : $(TGT_LIB) $(TGT_TESTS)
        $(BUILD_TESTS)

BUILD_TESTS = $(CXX) $(CF_ALL) $(LF_ALL) -o test/$@ $^
```

Of course, this works fine with `TGT_LIB`, which is a bunch of archives.  And of course, this is not going to work at all with `TGT_SO`, where these are all shared objects, and would need to be included with `-l...`.

Not surprisingly, breaking this into 2 separate rules (with single colon syntax) did not solve the problem.  It still included all of the .so objects in the build command.

After a bit of tinkering and reading, I have come with the following rules:

```
tests :: $(TGT_SO)

tests :: $(TGT_TESTS)
    $(BUILD_TESTS)
```

As I understand, the double-colon effectively makes these into 2 completely separate rules -- the first rule ensuring that the shared-objects are updated by all of their respective rules.  The second rule provides the recipe to build the shared objects.

As I said at the beginning, it appears that the above rules are working, but given my rather limited experience with Make, I'm really unsure of the implications of what I have done -- especially using a feature that the documentation describes as: "somewhat obscure and not often very useful...", and then goes on to suggest a use case: "to update a target differs depending on which prerequisite files caused the update, and such cases are rare." (quoted from [Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html#Double_002dColon))

Given that what I am trying to do must be quite common, and that the solution I found appears to misuse/abuse a feature of Make, I'm hoping someone can give me some advice on this.

## Edit 2014-05-21

As additional background information / clarification, there are rules scattered throughout the folder structure of the project which effectively has the same effect as:

```
$(TGT_TESTS) : $(TGT_SO)
```

Speaking specifically to the point that was raised in the one answer received to date -- while the double-colon rules potentially can have the effect of causing a blank rule to be executed if (one of) TGT_SO changes but (one of) TGT_TESTS does not (since that situation would result in only the first of the two rules above to be executed), practically speaking, a change in any one of the TGT_SO objects would also result in some/all of TGT_TESTS being rebuilt as well, thereby causing the second rule to be executed as well.

Thanks!
Shmuel

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
tests : $(TGT_SO) $(TGT_TESTS)
        $(BUILD_TESTS)

BUILD_TESTS = $(CXX) $(CF_ALL) $(LF_ALL) -o test/$@ $(filter %.o,$^)
```

You can probably do some transformation of the `$(TGT_SO)` or of the `$(filter %.so,$^) to reach to a list of -lXX

I have never used the double-colon rules, but from the description in the manual, if you only change one of the libraries (and no change in the objects), then only the first rule would be executed, which will result in trying to apply an implicit rule

(from the Manual, highlight is mine)

> Double-colon rules with the same target are in fact completely
>   separate from one another. Each double-colon rule is processed
>   individually, just as rules with different targets are processed.
>
> The double-colon rules for a target are executed in the order they
>   appear in the makefile. However, the cases where double-colon rules
>   really make sense are those where the order of executing the recipes
>   would not matter.
>
> Double-colon rules are somewhat obscure and not often very useful;
>   they provide a mechanism for cases in which the **method used to update
>   a target differs depending on which prerequisite files caused the
>   update**, and such cases are rare.
>
> Each double-colon rule should specify a recipe; if it does not, an
>   implicit rule will be used if one applies. See Using Implicit Rules.

Comment: indeed, while I was composing the question, a concept vaguely along the lines of the filter function that you suggested formed in my mind - although my lack of experience with Makefiles meant that the implementation (i.e. using filter) was not obvious to me.  As to the potential pitfall that you mention: this did not occur to me, if only for the reason that $(TGT_TESTS) has a dependency on $(TGT_SO), so this is less of a concern (this was not mentioned at all in my original question -- I will update it).  Does that fact make any difference in choosing between the 2 approaches?

Comment: One more small detail (really just a nit to pick) -- the variable should be named TGT_SO.  TGT_LIB was the older variable containing the archives; TGT_SO is the new variable containing the shared objects.  I did not reuse the same name to leave me the option of reverting (if I am ever able to solve a problem of over-zealous compiler optimization subverting my Factory self-registration classes...).  Also - thanks for the tip regarding transforming TGT_SO for a list of -lXX.